# Sequelize findAll dont retrieve expected records

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im using Sequelize ORM (v5.21.4) with Mysql 8.1 and when call method .findAll of my sequelize model dont retrieve all records, when execute same query on editor mysql returns a lot more.

cursoSenceModel.js

```
const CursoSenceModel = sequelize.define('curso', {
id:{
    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field:'cs_id',
    primaryKey:true,
    autoIncrement: true
},
codigoCurso:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_id',
    allowNull: false
},
rutOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_rut_otec'
},
dvOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_dv_otec'
},
razonSocial:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_nombre_otec'
},
acreditacion:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    field:'cuse_acreditacion'
},
ingresoSolicitud:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    field:'cuse_ingreso_solicitud'
},
terminoVigencia:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    field:'cuse_termino_vigencia'
},
comuna:{
    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field:'comu_id'
},
emailOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_email_otec'
},
webOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_web_otec'
},
horasTeoricas:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_horas_teoricas'
},
horasPractica:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_horas_practicas'
},
horasElearning:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_horas_elearning'
},
participantes:{
    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field:'cuse_participantes'
},
area:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_area'
},
especialidad:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_especialidad'
},
objetivoCurso:{
    type:DataTypes.TEXT,
    field:'cuse_objetivo_curso'
},
modalidadInstruccion:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_modalidad_instruccion'
},
montoPersonalInstruccion:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_personal_instruccion'
},
montoMaterialesConsumo:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_materiales_consumo'
},
montoMaterialDidactico:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_material_didactico'
},
montoUtilizacionLocal:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_utilizacion_local'
},
montoUtilizacionEquipos:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_utilizacion_equipos'
},
montoMovimientosViaticoTraslado:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_movimientos_viatico_traslado'
},
montoGastosGenerales:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_gastos_generales'
},
montoUtilidad:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_monto_utilidad'
},
valorTotalCurso:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_valor_total_curso'
},
valorEfectivoParticipante:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_valor_efectivo_participante'
},
valorImputableParticipante:{
    type:DataTypes.DECIMAL,
    field:'cuse_valor_imputable_participante'
},
ultimaActualizacion:{
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    field:'cuse_ultima_actualizacion',
    allowNull: false
},
nombre:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_nombre'
},
direccionOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_direccion_otec'
},
fonoOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_fono_otec'
},
codigo:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_codigo'
},
vigencia:{
    type:DataTypes.BIGINT,
    field:'cuse_vigencia'
},
clienteComercial:{
    type:DataTypes.BIGINT,
    field:'cuse_id_cliente_comercial'
},
tipoCurso:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_tipo_curso'
},
tipoElearning:{
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    field:'cuse_tipo_elearning'
},
tipoOtec:{
    type:DataTypes.TINYINT,
    field:'cuse_tipo_otec'
},
}, {
    tableName: 'sgc_cursos_sence',
    timestamps: false
});

CursoSenceModel.sync();

module.exports = CursoSenceModel;
```

code

```
const cursosBD = await CursoSenceModel.findAll({
        attributes:['codigoCurso'],
        where:{
            codigoCurso:ids
        },
        raw:true
    });
console.log('cursosSence',cursosBD);
```

cursosBD returns 17 records but the same query on Mysql returns 40.

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Yx4.png)

I've tried upgrade to Sequelize v6 but same issue.

Comment: You are using `IN` in your SQL.  the equivalent Sequelize code is `where: { codigoCurso: { [Op.in]: ids }}` https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators

Comment: @Emma He used the short-hand syntax that is mentioned in the link you provided: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#shorthand-syntax-for-opin

Comment: Though I don't see the documentation of v5 mentions the same short-hand syntax

Comment: You didn't show the result of Sequelize query.

Comment: It will be helpful to show the generated query from Sequelize and compare that query to the SQL you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

In Sequelize v5 you need to add `Op.in` operator here is the code

```
const Sequelize = require('Sequelize');

const { Op } = Sequelize;
const cursosBD = await CursoSenceModel.findAll({
        attributes:['codigoCurso'],
        where:{
            codigoCurso:{[Op.in]: ids}
        },
        raw:true
    });
console.log('cursosSence',cursosBD);
```

Comment: BTW Op was also in the versions before 5.